# facebook application ssl(https) problem?

Tags: php, facebook, ssl

This is my [facebook application.](http://apps.facebook.com/gunlukburcpaylas/) Facebook want SSL address from me (in applications panel)

But I haven't got [SSL](https://apps.facebook.com/gunlukburcpaylas/).

What can I do?

Comment: Install SSL? A cert doesn't cost much and takes only a minute or two to set up on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can leave the SSL address empty for now, but facebook is moving towards requiring all apps to have a secure address to improve security and to provide a better https browsing experience for their users.

You have two choices:

1. Buy and install a certificate (probably the best route, but will cost something)
2. Use a service like http://www.social-server.com/ that will provide an adaptor for you

Best of luck!

Comment: "For now" means [until October 1, 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/499/).

Comment: Choice #3: Run your app on Heroku and receive free hosting AND a free SSL certificate.

Comment: @hammar 2011 was two years ago, am I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Yusuf, it is important to use SSL to protect your facebook application and allow people who are accessing your app from https not leave it or have to switch to http instead. There are two ways for you to do that:

1. buy ssl certificate from your hosting provider; or
2. use free facebook apps hosting which supports SSL, such as http://hostfb.com

i'm hosting mine app with them and it works perfectly. Plus, now people stopped complaining about having to switch from https to http when viewing/using my app. I should say, we have to listen to people, as long as we provide the service to people.